# Specify which of my machine's IP4 or IP6 addresses is to be used for a curl request

Tags: ip, curl, ipv6, ipv4

My linux box has 3 IP4 addresses and a range of IP6 addresses.

Supposing I wish to make a `curl` fetch, how to stipulate from *which* address the request emanates?

Note: I'm actually using Python/PyCurl, however I'm interested in both bash+curl and curl-only solutions. If curl-only I can implement with PyCurl. If bash+curl, I can rewrite my code in bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the  `--interface` option? From `man curl`:

> --interface
>
> Perform an operation using a specified interface. You can
> enter interface name, IP address or host name. An example
> could look like:
>
> curl --interface eth0:1 https://www.example.com/
>
> If this option is used several times, the last one will be used.

Note that you may also use  a specific DNS interface.